# Angular how to update data from the other component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using an angular 6.0 and this is the structure of my some components.

```
heroes
|--hero-detail
|  |--hero-detail.component.ts|htmlcss|spec.ts
|--hero-list
|  |--hero-list.component.ts|html|css|spec.ts
|--shared
|  |--hero-button.component.ts|html|css|spec.ts
|  |--hero.model.ts
|  |--hero.service.ts|spec.ts
|--heroes.component.ts|html|css|spec.ts
|--heroes.module.ts
|--heroes-routing.module.ts
```

I am creating a new `hero` from `hero-detail`, and my question is, is it possible to update the list of `hero` in `hero-list` after I add some `hero` from `hero-detail`?

this is how I add the hero

**`hero-detail`**

```
onSubmit() {
    add();
}

add(): void {
    this.heroService.addHero( this.heroForm.value as Hero)
      .subscribe(hero => {
        this.heroService.heroes.push(hero);
        // This is how I notify the list.
        this.heroService.updateSource = true;
    });
}
```

my `hero-list` is using a `mat-table` and this is how I get the data.

```
getHeroList(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(
        result => {
        this.heroService.heroes = result;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.heroService.heroes);

        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
    );
}

// This is how I check if the hero is successfully added.
get isUpdateSource(): {
  return this.heroService.updateSource;
}
doUpdateSource(): void {
  console.log("update source");
  // getHeroList(); // This is not working.
}
```

but after getting the `isUpdateSource()` I try to log some result but it is spamming..

**`hero-list.html`**

```
<div class="col-sm-12" *ngIf="isUpdateSource; then doUpdateSource();">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>..</mat-table>
</div>
```

**`hero.service`**

```
export class HeroService {
  updateSource: boolean; 

  private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,

  ) { }

  /**
   * Handle Http operation that failed.
   * Let the app continue.
   * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
   * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
   */
  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      this.log('${operation} failed: ${error.message}');

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

  private log(message: string) {
    console.log(message);
  }

  /** POST: add a new hero to the server */
  addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
    return this.http.post<Hero>(heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((hero: Hero) => this.log(`added hero w/ id=${hero.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero>('addHero'))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your service file as well here?

Comment: @PardeepJain is right.post your service file.

Comment: I updated my question sorry I forgot the service.

Comment: What is not working with `getHeroList()`? Maybe you also need to write `this.getHeroList()` (added this)

Comment: No, I mean calling also that function is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You never set this.heroService.updateSource to false, thus making ngIf continuously spam updates.

Comment: I try to set the `this.heroService.updateSource = false` inside the `doUpdateSource()` and here's what I got. `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'.`

Comment: @Jer that means the ngIf directive is checking and changing a specific variable too often. I would solve your issue differently; having a reference to both components in 'heroes' component makes you update the list from detail, through heroes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as carsten said, I need to set the `this.heroService.updateSource` to `false` to stop the spamming of `logs` but I'd encounter this error.

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'
```

So to solve the problem I add some logic to my application.

I've created an additional `hasData` variable and always set to `true` to always show the `table`.

**`hero-list.component.ts`**

```
export class HeroListComponent {
  hasData: boolean;
  constructor() {
    hasData = true;
  }
}
```

then I changed my `hero-list.component.html`

```
<div class="col-sm-12" *ngIf="hasData||isUpdateSource">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>..</mat-table>
</div>
```

then I changed my `hero-list.component.ts` and here, I set the `this.heroService.updateSource` into `false` instead inside the `doUpdateSource()`.

```
get isUpdateSource() {
  if (this.heroService.updateSource) {
    this.heroService.updateSource = false; //
    this.getHeroList();
  }
  return this.heroService.updateSource;
}
```